# Matlab: Coding with arrays and writing data to excel sheet

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, region

I have obtained blood vessels of an eye in an image variable ves. I found the number of connected components(8-connectivity) as blobs. For each blob I need to calculate the Area, Major axis length and Centroid and store these values in a matrix testfv (each row corresponding to each property).For a single blob, Area returns a 1x1 struct, Centroid returns a 1x2 struct, and MajorAxisLength returns a 1x1 struct. So ,I guess depending on the number of blobs the number of cells required to store the values of Areas, Centroids and MajorAxisLength's vary, so using just one testfv to store these values as I have done would be wrong. 
Is it possible? This is the code I tried(i assumed that testfv has 25 columns which allows me to store upto 8 blobs info)

```
[labeledImage numberOfBlobs] = bwlabel(ves, 8);
col=numberOfBlobs*2;
testfv = zeros(3,col);

for i=1:col
blobMeasurements = regionprops(labeledImage, 'Area');
testfv(1,col) = [blobMeasurements.Area];
blobMeasurements = regionprops(labeledImage, 'MajorAxisLength');
testfv(2,col)= [blobMeasurements.MajorAxisLength];
blobMeasurements = regionprops(labeledImage, 'Centroid');
testfv(3,col) = [blobMeasurements.Centroid];
end
```

I am getting the following error....

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> alpha1 at 191 <br/>
testfv(1,col) = [blobMeasurements.Area];
```

Also, I need to write the data of the testfv matrix to an excel sheet file. How do I that ? 
Would really appreciate the help as I am new to Matlab.

Comment: [`xslwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) works to write to Excel files, but only on Windows with Excel installed. Otherwise, use [`dlmrwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) or similar.

Comment: The `Subscripted assignment...` error means that the shape of the data on the right side of the equal sign is not the same as the space you're trying to stick it in on the left side. Without knowing more about the code, I don't think I can say for sure, but you may need to pick a part of the `blobMeasurements.Area` struct to assign to the `testfv` matrix, perhaps something like `blobMeasurements.Area(:)`

Comment: yea..I think I got it. `blobMeasurements(i).Area` gives the area of blob i and as for Centroid `blobMeasurements(i).Centroid(1) and blobMeasurements(i).Centroid(2)` gives the co-ordinates of the centroid.